# prograss bar not displaying using AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

I just wrote a code that need to show progress bar when ever interacting with server.but it is not working if i call dismiss method in below code.

```
public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String result;
    public ProgressDialog progressbar;
    static Context context; 


    public AsyncClass(Context context,String result) {
        this.context = context;
        this.result = result;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            URI u = new URI(params[0]);
            // url = Urls.SENDMOVIE_REQUEST_URL;
            HttpGet HG = new HttpGet(u);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(HG);
            //httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.d("result", result);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result;  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressbar = new ProgressDialog(context);
        progressbar.setCancelable(true);
        progressbar.setMessage("loading....");
        progressbar.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        progressbar.setProgress(0);

        progressbar.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        progressbar.dismiss(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Check the declaration of the progressbar.  Don't you need to initialize the object globally?

Comment: Have you tried doing it inside onProgressUpdate()?

Comment: @Iqbal it's is global within his asynctask

Comment: How do you start the AsyncTask?

Comment: Try to remove this line :  progressbar.setProgress(0);

Comment: static Context context; <- keeping static references to activities is bad, it introduces memory leaks.

Comment: Try changing the following line,    progressbar = new ProgressDialog(context);  to progressbar = new ProgressDialog(YourActivityName.this);   Give the name of activity instead of context and try.

Comment: @Deepika He can't because his AsyncTask is a outer class and its need a context.

Comment: yes i am calling same Async Task in five activity's

Comment: Just check that for every activity progress dialog should be dismissed before in another activity your asyncTask being executing.

Comment: actually my problem is when i am using dismiss in post execute the progress bar is not appearing other wise it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not showing because of  `progressbar.setProgress(0);`

just remove it & try.

And If you want progressUpdates you need to do like this:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override 
    protected void onPreExecute() { 
        super.onPreExecute(); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        //Copy you logic to calculate progress and call 
        publishProgress("" + progress); 
    } 

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {        
    mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS); 
    } 
}
```

**Edited Iqbal's answer**

```
 private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public ProgressTask(){ 
           dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
           dialog.setCancelable(false);
        } 

        /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */  
        /** application context. */ 
          @Override 
         protected void onPreExecute() {  
               this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait"); 
                this.dialog.show(); 
          } 

          protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
                  /** * Write your code */  
           } 

          @Override 
           protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) { 
                if (dialog.isShowing()) { 
                      dialog.dismiss(); 
                }  
                if (success) { 
                    // display UI 
                 } 
           } 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this below code it shall do the job for you

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);
    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */ 
    /** application context. */
      @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() { 
           this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait"); 
            this.dialog.show(); 
      }

      protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
              /** * Write your code */ 
       }

      @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) { 
            if (dialog.isShowing()) { 
                  dialog.dismiss(); 
            } 
            if (success) { 
                // display UI
             }
       }
 }
```

Edit:

Add the initialization of progress bar in the constructor as

```
public AsyncClass(Context context,String result) {
        this.context = context;
        this.result = result;
        progressbar = new ProgressDialog(context);
}
```

And remove it from internecine().

Comment: Then declare the progress dialog in the constructor of asyncTask and pass the context from your activity to the asyncTask.

Comment: Then the problem may be in calling the asyncTask. How are you doing that? And did you debug? How does the execution flow go. Is it proper?

Comment: no.if i don't use dismiss in post execute it working properly,but not dismissing after some time

Comment: OK.. check the Edit in my answer, hope this will help you.